# React-Native Expo, Facebook login not working on Android device

Tags: android, react-native, facebook, expo

1. SDK Version: 39
2. Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all): android

Here is the snack: https://snack.expo.io/@tolgaduzenli/fb_login
IOS working fine on real device but android getting login error.
I just created FB app on FB developer account and didnt add any platform (ios or android) for login.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this!? For me it works when i create a build locally, but it fails when i builds built with fastlane. Im finding it really hard to debug.

Answer (score 0):

For Android, you would have to add Platform and add your device key hash in platform's settings like defined here [Expo Facebook Docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v36.0.0/sdk/facebook/)

Comment: I have done the same and I still am experiencing same error.....